# Why doesn't the Radio Button enable the disabled Submit button

Tags: html, radio-button, submit-button

Should be a Standard HTML5 Question, but for the life of me I can't find a straight forward answer.

When I have the following code (snipped but tested in jsfiddle):

```
<form>
   <input type="radio" name="color" value="black" required />
   <input type="radio" name="color" value="white" />
   <input type="submit" value="Click Here" disabled="disabled"/>
</form>
```

I do not have the ability to click the button after the radio button has been chosen. Searching for almost an hour for an answer (could be my google-foo is waning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disabled is a html attribute,as it can not be applied with a condition.It permanently disable the element until the attribute is removed.It is good to use angular's 'ng-disabled'.https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Comment: Aha moment. I was using ng-disabled for the prior tests, then when the radio button wasn't working, I wrote the jsfiddle as a test, and forgot the ng- so of course my last 3 runs without radio-buttons were working, but with in a different window, just would not enable that button. 

Comparing apples to oranges.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio][name=color]').change(function() {
        $('input[type=submit]').removeAttr('disabled')
    }); });
```

[https://jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/PrabuB/ka048k2n/)

Comment: I know this is late, but, I didn't tag jquery/angular, so its not acceptable as an answer